# Simple Lie Moufang loops

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-theory

Are there any simple Lie Moufang loops besides simple Lie groups and (modulo the center) special linear, orthogonal, and unitary loops over the octonions, split-octonions, and bioctonions?